# jQuery .trigger() isn't being caught

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does jQuery .trigger() or .triggerHandler() work across two separate JavaScript files? I have a timeline that when interacted with, triggers a function

`scrubbingToTime(position)`. In a separate JavaScript file, I want to detect when `scrubbingToTime(position)` is being called, so I was looking into jQuery .trigger(). The code is hard to reproduce, but the idea was that it was like:

`timeline.js`

```
function scrubbingToTime(position) {
     $(document).trigger("scrub", [position]);
}
```

`catch.js`

```
$(document).on("scrub", function(e, pos) {
     console.log("Time Changed!");
});
```

This does not work, however if the trigger and on are in the same file, it works fine. For example,

`timeline.js`

```
function scrubbingToTime(position) {
     $(document).trigger("scrub", [position]);

     $(document).on("scrub", function(e, pos) {
           console.log("Time Changed!");
     });
}
```

This actually console.logs the `Time Changed!` message. Is there any reason why the first (what I want) won't work?

Comment: Being in separate files should make no difference. You did not post anything about how `scrubbingToTime()` is called, so it's hard to provide any help.

Comment: Check if order of statements matter. Then make sure both the separate files are loaded and calling this function.

Comment: @Pointy The code is pretty long, but scrubbingToTime is called on a jQuery drag event. I know for certain the function is reached/called.

Comment: Well I am 100% certain that the jQuery `.trigger()` function does work. Now, `.triggerHandler()` has different (and somewhat weird) behavior, but `.trigger()` is pretty simple.

Comment: @stWrong Order of statements are not important - if I put the `on` before the `trigger`, it still only works when they are in the files together

Comment: @Pointy I know it's being called, when `trigger()` and `on` are in the same function, `scrubbingToTime`, the console.log works fine. The `on` just doesnt catch anything when in separate files

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the order of the JS loading is correct.

If you are loading your `catch.js` file first, then `timeline.js` won't know about scrub because it hasn't been loaded yet.